# Is there any app to always display time in touch bar?

Tags: macbook-pro, applications, customization, open-source, touch-bar

I would like to know if there's any way to always display current time in the touch bar in latest MacBook Pro.

When using browsers and other applications in full screen, I'm unable to view the top status bar by default.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here you go.

[image]

**Download from here**: https://github.com/nihalsharma/Clock-Bar/files/1801968/Clock.Bar.app.zip

**Repo**: https://github.com/nihalsharma/Clock-Bar

**Medium**: https://medium.com/@nihalsharma/clock-right-on-the-touch-bar-fd3ed4b392b2

**Product Hunt**: https://www.producthunt.com/posts/clock-bar

You can install the app directly through `brew install --cask clock-bar`

Answer (score 11):

You can use [BetterTouchTool](https://www.boastr.net) to add custom widgets to the Touch Bar.

[image]

that's the result:

[image]

Here's the example:
https://docs.bettertouchtool.net/docs/touch_bar_widgets.html